# Force a service to destroy?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm using Angular 2+.

As part of a ngOnDestroy for a component, I'd like to destroy/delete a service instantiation.

Is this possible?

Anyone know how?

And also of course, the next time the component is loaded, I'd like to recreate the service and then destroy when the component dies.

Edit:

What I'm trying to achieve is a dedicated web socket per component. And when a component gets destroyed (ngOnDestroy), to disconnect the websocket.

Comment: Why do you want to destroy it?

Comment: Please use the angularjs tag for version 1.X, and angular for versions 2+ (I have already retagged)

Comment: I believe if you make the service a provider at the component level, rather than the module level, this behaviour will occur for you.

Comment: Why not create a service acts as a factory? Inject it and have it build your service instance that you want to use for the life of the component. If that does not solve your issue you need to clarify what it is you are actually trying to do or maybe why you want to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have your module's providers array contain the service.  Remove it from there and just scope it to the component like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'yb-page',
  providers: [ServicePerComponent]
})
```

This basically will prevent angular from making a singleton for the service.  It will instead create a new service per component.  So once this component dies you can run the cleanup logic for the service in the onDestroy.

More info here: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection

Comment: This is exactly it. I do this and it does exactly what I want! Awesome.